# Android Map animateCamera does not reload map

Tags: android, google-maps

In my Android app I have to move the camera and draw a custom marker in the LocationCallback() everytime I get a location update when driving in a car. However It works fine. I just noticed that when I'm, using

```
gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)))
```

the map loads the needed parts when driving to a new location. But I dont like that moveCamera 'jumps' from a location to a new location. Using

```
gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)))
```

is just as smooth as I expect it to be, but in this case the map does not reload new contents so I'm driving in the middle of the fog of war!

Is there a possibility to get a smooth camera position update including a reloaded map?

Comment: As mentioned in https://issuetracker.google.com/71738889#comment14, have you tried using `moveCamera()` inside of an animator rather than using `animateCamera()`?

Comment: What is an "animator"? Have not found anything about it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator